# mvc c# caching in model class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

i have a Model like so

```
public class School{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}

   static private IEnumerable<School> school;
   static public IEnumerable<School> Schools(ContextDb context){
      if(school != null)
         return school;

      return(school = context.Schools.ToList());
   }
}
```

Now I have a page that inserts data into the table, using ajax. The problem is when the popup closes, I would regenerate the Academy.Schools again but since the "school" variable is not null (or is cached) it would return the previous data and not the refreshed data (with the newly added record.

With that said, how do i empy that private variable so I would trigger the "return(school = ..);" line in the class?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Model design is very strange (based on the given information it's hard to offer a better one, is is some kind of ActiveRecord pattern?), but with the current design you need a new method which empties the "cache" e.g. set `school` to `null`:

```
public class School{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}

   static private IEnumerable<School> school;
   static public IEnumerable<School> Schools(ContextDb context){
      if(school != null)
         return school;

      return(school = context.Schools.ToList());
   }

   public static void InvalidateSchools()
   { 
       school = null;
   }
}
```

After calling `School.InvalidateSchools` the subsequent call to `School.Schools` will return the new data.

Comment: well, for the models i use for constants (eg. gender, country, etc) that's what i use for caching, i guess i was wrong to assume that this one will have the same use. this gets updated more frequently than others.

Comment: @gdubs for catalog like entities like (gender, country) I think this approach is OK. But for frequent changing ones like School maybe you don't need caching at all or use some cache invalidation logic (explicit, time based, etc.) like the one what I've shown.

Comment: i actually might go with that option. never thought of that.. clearing the cached variable.. thanks!